# Baketball data output in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Please help me solve a problem I haven't been able to cope with for the last 6 days. The problem is non-standard, so if you want I will pay for its solution. I need to **organize the raw data** of the basketball games from column A according **to a sample that I made manually next to it**. Below is my vision on how to do it, but probably you have a much better way.

1. Output the Tournament column and the 4 rows following it.  Output the cell that is above the date (highlighted in beige) by the criterion:

- does not contain the words "c OT" and "From the"
- does not contain a ":" sign
- if first 2 criteria are fulfilled, but there is no data for tournament, then pull next tournament from above

2. Output the cell under the line three -point throws or two-point

- each next match can be identified by a row with a date
  Hope for your help, thank you
  File link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u5N4mud5tcOHRoSCRbiElduETYS7blB84bhpwFhtOi0/edit#gid=0

[image]

Comment: This seems to not be achievable using solely Google Sheet functions. Have you ever thought of using custom formula via scripting?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't got so much expertise for script codes. Do yo know a script that fit in for this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey user: [*TheGunner4 / Get Job*]

*Here's [one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u5N4mud5tcOHRoSCRbiElduETYS7blB84bhpwFhtOi0/edit#gid=1522618583) you may test out:*

```js
=let(Λ,map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(isdate(Σ),let(r1_,offset(Σ,-1,), r7_,Σ:offset(Σ,7,),
     iferror({if(regexmatch(r1_,":|с ОТ|^From the"),,r1_),torow(offset(Σ,,,4)),chooserows(r7_,xmatch(H2,r7_)+1),chooserows(r7_,xmatch(I2,r7_)+1)})),))),
     let(Γ,filter(Λ,index(Λ,,2)<>""),choosecols({Γ,scan(,index(Γ,,1),lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))},8,2,3,4,5,6,7)))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, you exposed me, but anyway thank you very much wizard!